# Pass Dataframe to Apply function pandas as argument

Tags: python, pandas, apply

Is possible to pass a DataFrame to an `apply` function like this?

```
df2 = df1.apply(func,axis=1,args=df2)
def func(df1,df2):
    # do stuff in df2 for each row of df1
    return df2
```

The two DataFrames do not have the same length.

Comment: I assume `return df2` should be indented?

Comment: `args=(df2, )` And yes it is possible. But there is a 90% chance of a better way to do this than what you're doing.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ thanks for the hint. Suggestions for better ways?

Comment: Can't say unless it is known what `func` is doing. Do you want to open a new question?

Comment: It would help if you gave us some sample data according to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) docs:

> `DataFrame.apply(func, axis=0, broadcast=False, raw=False, reduce=None,
>   args=(), **kwds)`
>
> Applies function along input axis of
>   DataFrame.
>
> **`args`** : `tuple`
>
> Positional arguments to pass to function in addition to
>   the array/series.

The right way is to pass your arguments in a tuple, like this:

```
df1.apply(func, axis=1, args=(df2, ))
```

Further improvements to your code would be possible if it were known what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. That solved a problem I was having.  I had a function I wanted to apply to df1 which initially had no arguments, then I changed it to having a single df2 argument.

So I went from 
`df1.apply(func, axis=1)`
to
`df1.apply(func, axis=1, args=(df2))`
but that resulted in a warning about redundant parentheses so I changed it to
`df1.apply(func, axis=1, args=df2)`
which resulted in the error "The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous."
So I changed it as you suggested to
 `df1.apply(func, axis=1, args=(df2, ))`
and it is working just as intended.

Comment: Thanks @cs95.  I forgot to tag you in the previous comment.